# How to play dropbox audio file using JukeBox using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, dropbox-api

I have integrate Dropbox API ([Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#tutorial)) in my project and want to access only audio files.

Create share links using Dropbox API.

Now, I want to play that song using Jukebox or any audio player from shareable URL.

I have tried multiple links to play using Jukebox, it running fine.

I am facing in only Dropbox shareable link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared links, e.g., from [`createSharedLinkWithSettings`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/SharingRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox13SharingRoutes28createSharedLinkWithSettingsFT4pathSS8settingsGSqCCS_7Sharing18SharedLinkSettings__GCS_10RpcRequestCS1_28SharedLinkMetadataSerializerCS1_43CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsErrorSerializer_), point to an HTML preview page, and not the file content itself.

If you need the actual file content, e.g., to use it in a media player, you have a few options:

1) Use [`download(path:rev:overwrite:destination:)`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes8downloadFT4pathSS3revGSqSS_9overwriteSb11destinationFTCSo5NSURLCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse_S1__GCS_19DownloadRequestFileCCS_5Files22FileMetadataSerializerCS4_23DownloadErrorSerializer_) to download the file to disk.

2) Use [`download(path:rev:)`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes8downloadFT4pathSS3revGSqSS__GCS_21DownloadRequestMemoryCCS_5Files22FileMetadataSerializerCS2_23DownloadErrorSerializer_) to download the file to memory. (Not recommended for large files.)

3) Use [`getTemporaryLink(path:)`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes16getTemporaryLinkFT4pathSS_GCS_10RpcRequestCCS_5Files32GetTemporaryLinkResultSerializerCS2_31GetTemporaryLinkErrorSerializer_) to get a temporary link to the file. This may be the best option if you need a URL to give to a media player.

Comment: Thanks dear for ans. I will upvote ur ans once i complete this.

Comment: Hello Greg :- I have try option 1 and 2. that is file. But my requirement is live streaming, so i need use option 3.
As i have used API V2, 3rd option is not available. :(
Any other option.

Comment: The third option is part of Dropbox API v2. For reference, I linked to the documentation for it in SwiftyDropbox, which uses API v2. Make sure you're using the latest version of SwiftyDropbox though. (E.g., if you're using CocoaPods, do `pod update`.)

Comment: @Greg the getTemporaryLink(path:) is not returning the url else it is giving error while converting to URL "Cannot convert value of type 'RpcRequest<Files.GetTemporaryLinkResultSerializer, Files.GetTemporaryLinkErrorSerializer>?' to type 'URL". Thanks in advance

Comment: @PratyushPratik It sounds like you're trying to convert the return value of `getTemporaryLink` to `URL`, but it does not return any kind of `URL` directly. Please refer to [the documentation for an example of making an RPC call like this](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#rpc-style-request).